# Rspec controller test - how to pass arguments to a method I'm testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I want to test this method in my controller.

```
def fetch_match_displayed_count(params)
  match_count = 0
  params.each do |param|
    match_count += 1 if param[1]["result"] && param[1]["result"] != "result"
  end
  match_count
end
```

This is the test I've written so far.

```
describe "fetch_match_displayed_count" do
  it "should assign match_count with correct number of matches" do
    params = {"result_1"=>{"match_id"=>"975", "result"=>"not_match"}, "result_2"=>{"match_id"=>"976", "result"=>"match"}, "result_3"=>{"match_id"=>"977", "result"=>"not_sure"}, "result_4"=>{"match_id"=>"978", "result"=>"match"}, "result_5"=>{"match_id"=>"979", "result"=>"not_match"}, "workerId"=>"123", "hitId"=>"", "assignmentId"=>"", "controller"=>"mt_results", "action"=>"create"}
    controller.should_receive(:fetch_match_displayed_count).with(params)
    get :fetch_match_displayed_count, {params:params}
    assigns(:match_count).should == 5
  end
end
```

My problem seems to lie in this line `get :fetch_match_displayed_count, {params:params}`
The method is expecting params, but is getting nil.

I have two questions.

1. Should this method be in a helper and not in the controller itself (per Rails convention)?
2. How do I submit a get request and pass `params` in my test?

Comment: Is this an action? I'm guessing no.

Comment: @zetetic No, it's a method that I call in my create action.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. I had to make the method a private method and then submit a get request on the `create` action. Then, I can just expect the following: `controller.should_receive(:fetch_match_displayed_count).with(params).and_return(5)
`

Comment: heh..beat me by seconds. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should test the public interface of your class. For a controller, this means you test actions, not helper methods.

You should be able to make this work by setting up one or more separate test cases that call the appropriate action(s), then use a message expectation to test that the helper method is called with the right arguments -- or test that the helper method does what it is supposed to do (sets the right instance variables/redirects/etc).

Comment: Great, thanks zetetic. Your question in my post helped me solved this.